# Which search terms do we top?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, answer-quality, question-quality, search

I noticed today that if you search Google [for `Purim Torah`](https://www.google.com/#q=purim+torah&*) or [for `"Purim Torah"`](https://www.google.com/#q=%22purim+torah%22&*), our [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) tag landing page is now the *first* result, above the Wikipedia entry.

This fact indicates that for this niche topic, we have a comparative advantage over other places on the English-language internet. When we noticed last year that this was happening, we [improved the tag wiki](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=27911120#27911120) to make it more likely that this niche placement helps promote the rest of our content.

So, I'm wondering which other terms, when searched on Google, bring up our content high in the search results? In which other Judaism topics do we have a comparative search advantage over the rest of the English-language Internet?

We could use this information to focus efforts on tag wiki improvement and also actual content improvement.

Please post one search term or family of very-closely-related search terms per answer. The following factors make an answer stronger than others:

- Search result placement
- Overall importance within Judaism of the topic
- Evidence that it's a search term people search for<sup>1</sup>
- Suggestions for how we could improve the associated content

---

<sup>1. For example: Each year, around Purim, `Purim Torah` rises in search-popularity to be about 3% as popular as `Judaism`, [according to Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=purim%20torah,judaism).</sup>

Comment: We also insist on including the exact phrase "purim torah" thrice in every post about it, so we are giving ourselves a huge advantage in SEO.

Comment: @DoubleAA Presumably. One could imagine other terms that tend to come up many times in posts about that topic, either here or generally. This is probably true of most proper names of people, holidays, etc.

Comment: Many if not most of those have multiple spelling variants, both among the posts and among potential search terms.

Comment: @DoubleAA There are many factors that lead to our search-advantage with Purim Torah. Some or all of them (or other factors) may apply to some other terms, to varying degrees.

Comment: Note that Yodeyans may have search results catered to their inclinations. To get purer results, search in historyless ("incognito" in Chrome) mode or using DuckDuckGo (which I *think* is always historyless).

Comment: I was just about to point that out, @msh210. The Purim Torah search result holds in Chrome incongnito, at least for me.

Comment: Right now, ["why don't jews accept our lord"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36320049#36320049), but [not in a good way](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55237/5323).

Comment: We also top "mi yodeya" in search, but not everything about that result is good. Bam discussion started [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38783390#38783390).